# How to get bootstrap components to work with blazor

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor, .net-6.0

I am using .Net6 and Blazor. I am trying to get a bootstrap dropdown menu but the button is not dropping down. Is there something I am missing?

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Manage
              </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Blazor by default does not add the bootstrap javascript files. You need to add the libraries  or perform the equivalent class manipulation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: If you load the Bootstrap 5 css and javascript bundle in your layout you can use the controls in any razor page.  Copy and paste the examples from the Bootstrap site and they work the same.  The only problem that I've encountered is that the carousel control will not auto play as in a normal html page.

Comment: I had a similar problem, with very similar code. Changing the class of the `dropdown-menu` div to `dropdown-item` fixed that problem, though I'm still having other problems with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't by default have the Bootstrap JS files loaded, and it's not necessarily a good idea to use them.  You can code the equivalent functionality in the component code.

Two of many options:

1. Use a simple component to hold the toggle logic.
2. Built into the page with the logic in the page code.

#### Demo Page

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<div class="row">

    <div class="m-2 col-auto">
        <DropdownButton ButtonText="My Dropdown" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </DropdownButton>

    </div>

    <div class="m-2 col-auto">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a @onclick=this.ToggleDropDown class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Manage
            </a>
            @if (state)
            {
                <div class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool state = false;

    private void ToggleDropDown()
        => this.state = !this.state;
}
```

#### DropdownButton.razor

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a @attributes=UserAttributes @onclick=this.ToggleDropDown>
        @ButtonText
    </a>
    <div class="@this.dropdownCss" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        @ChildContent
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    private bool show = false;
    private string dropdownCss => show
        ? "dropdown-menu show"
        : "dropdown-menu";

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> UserAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "DropDown Button";

    private void ToggleDropDown()
        => this.show = !this.show;
}
```

Personally, I'd use 1.